# How to export const for all projects in react-native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

In Home.js, I have

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: ""
};
if (!firebase.app.lenght) {
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
}
```

And I need this code in other page, in case is Form.js for use firebase.push data

Comment: Your Question is not clear try to edit and explain better so ppl will know how to help You.

Answer (score 1):

if i understand correctly you need to learn how to properly export consts in a React Native project

you can create a new file and add your const there

> Constants.js

```
export const someData = {
  someUsefullData: true
};
export const someExtraData = {
  someExtra: ''
};
```

And then you can import them anywhere with a normal import

> import { someData, someExtraData } from 'pathToContants/Constants'